# Join two under-serving microservices in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm relatively new to GraphQL, and I'm having trouble joining data from two microservices.

Let's say I have two microservices, one with Cars sizes, and other with Car stock.

So the first one responds something like this:

`GET - /cars/sizes =>`

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "size": "big"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "size": "small"
  },
  ...
]
```

And the second, something like this

`GET - /cars/stock =>`

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "stock": 27
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "stock": 12
  },
  ...
]
```

How can I implement the `cars` resolver at Apollo GraphQL so a query like this:

```
query {
  cars {
    id
    size
  }
}
```

Doesn't ask the second microservice, but:

```
query {
  cars {
    id
    size
    stock
  }
}
```

Does it only once? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add stock lookup in the resolver for the stock field itself, rather than doing it as part of the car resolver. This way it'll only be executed if you actually query the stock field.

Comment: Buf for each car I'll be making a new HTTP Request to the `stock` microservice for each car... :(

Comment: If you memoize requests for the lifespan of a single query, you can make the same call as many times as you like with no penalty.  It's a bit of a hack, but a useful one. In an ideal world your microservices would expose endpoints that let you fetch batches of things by ID, then you could use something like Dataloader (in JavaScript) to fetch things more efficiently. I talk about optimal patterns a lot here: https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/optimizing-your-graphql-request-waterfalls-7c3f3360b051